MS Outlook keeps changing double quotes to chevron quotes
I’m using MS Office 365 for Small Business on Windows 11 (Slovenian language version). All updates regularly installed.
By default, Outlook’s AutoFormat As You Type setting changes double quotes "" to chevron quotes »«. This is strange, especially since Slovenian doesn't typically use chevron quotes. However, I’d like to disable this feature.
The problem is that, despite disabling this option, it mysteriously reverts back after some time. Sometimes, it happens after I close and reopen Outlook, or even after unlocking the computer from idle time.
Why does Outlook keep reverting to the default settings, and how can I prevent this from happening? It’s incredibly frustrating.
*I'm experiencing the same problem on both my home and office computer (same Windows and Office version).

If the solution described in my answer doesn't suit you, you may look into this answer I found.

Seems to work for now. I'll do some more testing.

Try typing quotes on US keyboard layout. Outlook and Word seem to differentiate quotes typed with Shift' (right of ;, which is right of L on ANSI layout) and quotes typed with Shift2 (or whatever you use to type double quotes in your input method).

Thank you, but this is unfortunately not acceptable for me, because I require the keyboard to be in SLO language so I can access all the characters of our alphabet.

I will award you the bounty, because it looks like the solution from your comment above did the trick.
